# Assign new amount to mask money

Tags: javascript, jquery, maskedinput

I have below code that will assign a value to some input and at the same time will trigger that value to mask money function. But it something not working for sure I don't know how to make it working.

```
$('#CourseFeeAmountFullTime').keypress(function(event){

  var amount = $(this).val();
  amount = amount.replace(/\,/g,'');
  amount = parseInt(amount,10);

  var duration = $('#DurationSemFullTimeId').val();

  if(amount != '' && duration != ''){
    var persemester = (amount/duration);
    var total_persem = persemester.toFixed(2);
    $('#PerSemAmountFullTime').val(total_persem).trigger('mask.maskMoney');;
  }
});
```

When I insert the amount 50000.00, it not assign mask money like this 50,000.00

Comment: Can you please make a demo snippet or fiddle :)?

Comment: refer this - http://jsfiddle.net/94h3n/